# In MIPS/SPIM, whats the difference between li and lw?

Tags: assembly, mips

After realizing how lost I am with assembly language and using MIPS, I decided to start from the basics and actually understand it.

Obviously MIPS code has specific purposes, but a lot of the stuff seems to do similar things and I'm having a hard time understanding some of the differences.

What is the difference between loading immediate.. (li) and loading a word.. (lw)? I'm not even sure what a "word" is. Or what the following does:

```
li $t0,y
lw $t0,0($t0)
```

Is it loading y into the register $t0 in the first line? And then loading 0($t0) as y?

Sorry, this is probably a really dumb question. If anyone could just explain what those two lines are doing and the difference between li/lw, i'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A `word` is a fixed-length sequence of bits.
On MIPS32, a `word` is 32 bits wide.
The instruction `lw $regA, offset($regB)` loads a word from the memory location specified by `offset($regB)` into register `regA`.
By contrast, `li reg, immediate` is **not a true instruction**. No MIPS cpu can execute `li`. It's a pseudo-instruction that is turned into a sequence of two instructions by the assembler:

```
lui $reg, [most significant 16 bits of immediate]
ori $regA, $regA, [least significant 16 bits of immediate]
```

`lui` loads the upper 16 bits of a 32-bit register with an immediate constant from the instruction, setting the lower 16 bits to zero.
`ori` takes the content of `$regA`, does a bitwise logical OR with the 16 bit immediate from the instruction, and stores the result back into `$regA`.

So, to sum up: `li $reg, immediate` will *always* put the *same* immediate into a register, while `lw $regA, offset($regB)` will load the *current* value from the memory location `offset($regB)`.